# Transformation matrix gone wrong

Tags: c#, matrix, multidimensional-array, transformation

I am trying to apply a affine transform to a point using translation , rotation and scaling.This is my code:

```cs
namespace PictureProcessor
{
    public class PointTranslator
    {
        public Point p;

        public PointTranslator(Point p)
        {
            this.p = p;
        }

        private double[,] Mul(double[,] x, double[,] y)
        {
            double[,] fin = new double[1, 3];
            int j = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                fin[0, i] += x[i, j] * y[0, i];
                j++;
            }

            return fin;
        }

        private Point Translation(Point p,double x,double y)
        {
            double[,]translationMatrix = new double[3, 3];

            translationMatrix[0, 0] = 1;
            translationMatrix[1, 0] = 0;
            translationMatrix[2, 0] = x;
            translationMatrix[0, 1] = 0;
            translationMatrix[1, 1] = 1;
            translationMatrix[2, 1] = y;
            translationMatrix[0, 2] = 0;
            translationMatrix[1, 2] = 0;
            translationMatrix[2, 2] = 1;

            double[,] pointPosition = p.point;
            double[,] newPointPosition = Mul(translationMatrix, pointPosition);

            p.point = newPointPosition;

            return p;
        }

        private Point Rotation(Point p,double angle)
        {
            double[,] rotationMatrix = new double[3, 3];

            rotationMatrix[0, 0] = Math.Cos(angle);
            rotationMatrix[1, 0] = -(Math.Sin(angle));
            rotationMatrix[0, 1] = Math.Sin(angle);
            rotationMatrix[1, 1] = Math.Cos(angle);
            rotationMatrix[2, 0] = 0;
            rotationMatrix[2, 1] = 0;
            rotationMatrix[0, 2] = 0;
            rotationMatrix[1, 2] = 0;
            rotationMatrix[2, 2] = 1;

            double[,] pointPosition = p.point;
            double[,]newPointPosition = Mul(rotationMatrix, pointPosition);

            p.point = newPointPosition;

            return p;
        }

        private Point Scaling(Point p,double x,double y)
        {
            double[,]scalingMatrix = new double[3, 3];

            scalingMatrix[0, 0] = x;
            scalingMatrix[1, 1] = y;
            scalingMatrix[2, 2] = 1;
            scalingMatrix[0, 1] = 0;
            scalingMatrix[1, 0] = 0;
            scalingMatrix[2, 0] = 0;
            scalingMatrix[0, 2] = 0;
            scalingMatrix[2, 1] = 0;
            scalingMatrix[1, 2] = 0;

            double[,] pointPosition = p.point;
            double[,] newPointPosition = Mul(scalingMatrix, pointPosition);

            p.point = newPointPosition;

            return p;
        }

        public Point act(int i,double x,double y,double angle)
        {
            Point myPoint;

            if (i == 0)
            {

               myPoint = Translation(p, x, y);
            }
            else if (i == 1)
            {
                myPoint = Rotation(p, angle);

            }
            else if (i == 2)
            {
                myPoint =  Scaling(p, x, y);
            }
            return p;
        }
    }
}
```

The first dimension is the width of the matrix and the second dimension is the height of the matrix.The Point is a class of its own:

```
namespace PictureProcessor
{
    public class Point
    {
        public double[,] point;
        
        public Color color;
        public Point(double x,double y, Color color)
        {
            double[,] point = new double[1, 3];

            point[0, 0] = x;
            point[0, 1] = y;
            point[0, 2] = 1;

            this.point = point;
            this.color = color;
        }
    }
}
```

When I created an object of the Point and the PointTranslator class and set the Point position to 15,15 then I called the PointTranslator and acted on the point with a id of 0->(translation) but the coordinates of the returned point didnt change.What am I doing wrong? I think I have implemented the Mul() function correctly.

Comment: Generally, this stuff is done in this order: scale, rotate, translate.